# SQL query to calculate frequency in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table `tab` in Hive that looks like this:

```
word | occurrences  
---- | -----------  
by   | 10
hi   | 1
same | 3
love | 6
```

I would like to calculate and display the frequencies of the words (occurrences divided by the sum of the entire column) using Hive query. For example, the frequency of the word 'by' is 10/(10+1+3+6) = 0.5.

I tried this:

```
SELECT word, occurrences, occurrences/SUM(occurrences) AS frequency
FROM tab
GROUP BY word, occurrences
ORDER BY frequency;
```

But it gives this:

```
word | occurrences | frequency
---- | ----------- | ---------
by   | 10          | 1
hi   | 1           | 1
same | 3           | 1
love | 6           | 1
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm not very good SQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT word, occurrences, occurrences/(SELECT SUM(occurrences) FROM tab) AS frequency
FROM tab
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY frequency;` try this, if it works, i wil add it as an answer

Comment: try,  `occurrences/SUM(occurrences) OVER() AS frequency`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below sql, used `SUM() OVER()` here

```
SELECT word, occurrences, occurrences/SUM(occurrences) OVER() AS frequency
FROM tab
ORDER BY frequency;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `GROUP BY` any column since you are looking to get a total of all the frequencies for the denominator.

```
SELECT a.word, a.occurrences, a.occurrences/b.total_freq AS frequency
FROM 
tab a CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(occurences) AS total_freq from tab) b
ORDER BY frequency;
```

By doing a cross join, you can use the `total_freq` for all the rows of `tab` table and then use it in the outer query as the denominator.

Comment: I tried this one too and it gives the desired result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
with a1 as

(

SELECT word, occurrences, occurrences/SUM(occurrences) OVER() AS frequency
FROM tab
ORDER BY frequency

)

select * from a1
```